# Getting JSON data into R data frame that has weird formatting

Tags: json, r

I'm trying to import this JSON into a data frame in R. The URL for the data is http://mooshe.pw/files/items_rs3.json

Here's the code I have:

```
library(jsonlite)

item.codes <- fromJSON('http://mooshe.pw/files/items_rs3.json')
```

However, I get the following error message when trying to run this:

```
    Error in feed_push_parser(buf) : 
  parse error: after key and value, inside map, I expect ',' or '}'
            "name": "Key block labelled "2"",       "members": true,        "t
                 (right here) ------^
```

So the value in some of the data has quote marks in it, meaning R has a hard time parsing the JSON and getting it as a data frame. How can I get around this?

Comment: It's invalid JSON. R isn't "having a tough time", it's rightly flagging an invalid file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RJSONIO::fromJSON` is a little more tolerant of irregular syntax, and will give you a list, which you can assemble into a list with `purrr`:

```
library(purrr)

l <- RJSONIO::fromJSON('http://mooshe.pw/files/items_rs3.json')

df <- l %>% transpose() %>% map_df(simplify)

df
## # A tibble: 23,972 × 6
##                  name members tradeable cosmetic modelid  value
##                 <chr>   <lgl>     <lgl>    <lgl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
## 1       Dwarf remains    TRUE     FALSE    FALSE    2595     -1
## 2             Toolkit    TRUE     FALSE    FALSE    2679     -1
## 3          Cannonball    TRUE      TRUE    FALSE    2413      5
## 4    Nulodion's notes    TRUE     FALSE    FALSE    2794     -1
## 5          Ammo mould    TRUE     FALSE    FALSE    2706      5
## 6  Instruction manual    TRUE     FALSE    FALSE    2794     10
## 7         Cannon base    TRUE      TRUE    FALSE   63866 187500
## 8        Cannon stand    TRUE      TRUE    FALSE   63876 187500
## 9      Cannon barrels    TRUE      TRUE    FALSE   63868 187500
## 10     Cannon furnace    TRUE      TRUE    FALSE   63870 187500
## # ... with 23,962 more rows
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

Again, it's invalid JSON that you need to fix. This is one way to do that:

```
library(magrittr)
library(stringi)
library(jsonlite)

readLines("http://mooshe.pw/files/items_rs3.json") %>% 
  stri_replace_all_regex('(")([[:alnum:][:blank:]]+)("")', "'$2'\"") %>% 
  fromJSON()
```